# Example for Openstack Ha setup with Juju?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I search for an Openstack HA-Setup example with Juju deployment (maybe only a yaml-file bundle for the ha-setup).

I already know the basics with hacluster-charm in relation. I found an old tutorial here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA but it is a little bit outdated.

I already have running a ha-setup with hacluster on the important units. I would like to compare it with an example. Especially if I can still optimize things z.b. with HaProxy / Memcached for speed up.
Maybe someone is ready to look at my setup (yaml-file) and give me useful hints?

I would be very happy if anyone could help me...

Comment: Please upload your `bundle.yaml` file to paste.ubuntu.com :)

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pF4hq9S6MD/

Comment: What do you think about my HA bundle?
We have a total of 9 servers:
3 for ceph (32 cores, 48gb RAM with several hdd + ssd)
3 for Compute (64 cores, 128gb RAM)
3 for Network and other services (32 cores, 64gb RAM)
Is there something you could optimize?

Comment: Your setup looks similar to what I saw in Miratis OS deployment with Fuel.
Have you configured machine interfaces from MAAS (eg. associated subnets to interfaces) or is it done automatically during deployment phase?